# Problems adding xom to Maven project

Tags: maven, xom

I am trying to use [xom](http://www.xom.nu/) in a Maven project but am getting the error
`Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xom:xom:jar:1.2.5: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer xom:xom:pom:1.2.5 from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo2_maven_org has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact xom:xom:pom:1.2.5 from/to repo2_maven_org (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2): null to http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/xom/xom/1.2.5/xom-1.2.5.pom    pom.xml /tahrir line 1  Maven Dependency Problem`

My `pom.xml` looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tahrirproject</groupId>
<artifactId>tahrir</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.mainClass>tahrir.TrMain</project.build.mainClass>
    <!-- I need to explicitly specify encoding to avoid non-standard, like was GBK or GB18030. Because I live in China. -->
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>codehaus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>tahrir.TrMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Proguard setup, see http://blog.boxofrats.com/2009/08/07/setting-up-maven-for-scala-and-proguard/ -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <options>
                    <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                    <option>-keep public class ${project.build.mainClass} { public
                        static void main(java.lang.String[]);}</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn</option>
                    <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>
                    <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>
                </options>
                <includeDependency>false</includeDependency>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-shrunk.jar</outjar>
                <libs>
                    <!-- WARNING: This is required on OSX, will need to be adjusted for 
                        other platforms because these jar files are in a different location -->
                    <lib>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/../Classes/jce.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo2_maven_org</id>
        <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>doodleproject-repo</id>
        <name>DoodleProject Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/maven2/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.doodleproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>numerics4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>args4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>140</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>13.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-db4o</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-m3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.seaglasslookandfeel</groupId>
        <artifactId>seaglasslookandfeel</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manged to fix the problem by clearing the `.m2/rerepository` folder and building the project again from scratch.